# Applying different weights to multiple lists grouped in list of lists - Python

Tags: python, nested-lists

I have the following list of lists:

```
list_of_lists=[[1,2,3], [4,5,2], [3,2,4]]
```

I want to create a function to apply a different weight for each of those inner lists.

So when I write `weighted_lists(list_of_lists,10,2,5.5)`:
- The first inner list should be multiplied by 10
- The second inner list should be multiplied by 2
- The third inner list should be multiplied by 5.5

So, as result I should have the following:

```
weighted_lists=[[10,20,30], [8,10,4], [16.5,11,22]]
```

Note that this function should support various numbers of inner lists (in some cases we might have 3, in other cases we might have 400).

Comment: Are you asking us to solve your homework question?

Comment: No. Just don't know how to make my code interact that way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might want to look into `numpy` for something like this:

```
In [14]: import numpy as np

In [15]: list_of_lists=[[1,2,3],[4,5,2],[3,2,4]]

In [16]: weights = [10, 2, 5.5]

In [17]: (np.array(list_of_lists) * np.array(weights)[:, None]).tolist()
Out[17]: [[10.0, 20.0, 30.0], [8.0, 10.0, 4.0], [16.5, 11.0, 22.0]]
```

Comment: I would just add a tolist() in the np array

Answer (score 2):

Here you go, `lol` is the list of lists.

```
def weighted_lists(lol, *weights):
    if len(lol) != len(weights):
        raise IndexError

    return [[weight*x for x in inner] for inner, weight in zip(lol, weights)]
```

Demo:

```
list_of_lists=[[1,2,3], [4,5,2], [3,2,4]]
print(weighted_lists(list_of_lists, 10, 2, 5.5)) # [[10, 20, 30], [8, 10, 4], [16.5, 11.0, 22.0]]
```

Answer (score 0):

If you prefer functional, you could do it using `itertools` and `operator.mul`:

```
list_of_lists = [[1, 2, 3], [4, 5, 2], [3, 2, 4]]
from itertools import izip, starmap, repeat
from operator import mul

def weighted_lists(l, *args):
    return (list(starmap(mul, izip(*(s, repeat(i))))) for s, i in izip(l, args))


print(list(weighted_lists(list_of_lists, 10, 2, 5.5)))
[[10, 20, 30], [8, 10, 4], [16.5, 11.0, 22.0]]
```

Answer (score 0):

Using `enumerate` and `lambda` you can achieve the same result.

```
list_of_lists = [[1,2,3], [4,5,2], [3,2,4]]

def weighted_lists(a_list_of_lists, *some_weights):
    weighted_list_of_list = []
    for i, a_list in enumerate(a_list_of_lists):
        new_list = map(lambda value: value * some_weights[i], a_list)
        weighted_list_of_list.append(new_list)

    return weighted_list_of_list
```

And a one liner:

```
f = lambda x, *y: [map(lambda v: v * y[i], l) for i, l in enumerate(x)]
```

Result:

```
>>> f(list_of_lists, 10, 2, 5.5)
[[10, 20, 30], [8, 10, 4], [16.5, 11.0, 22.0]]
>>> weighted_lists(list_of_lists, 10, 2, 5.5)
[[10, 20, 30], [8, 10, 4], [16.5, 11.0, 22.0]]
```